# Autocomplete location and Google Maps Nearby Places in Android studio, Do I need a billing account?

Tags: google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-autocomplete

I understand that for using the API that allows to provide autocomplete addresses and to show the nearby places in a maps, I need to have a billing account. It is just a universitary project, so I would not like to have a subscription. However, I read that when I enable billing on my account, I will not pay nothing. I'm not sure about these information. Anyone could give me more information?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use, pricing and billing of a third-party service and not about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes u should have a billing account. You just need to do just link your credit or debit card to your account unless your API will not work. Just add a your card u can get free 3 months trial

Comment: The question being off-topic, it didn't need an answer. Aside from that, your answer is plain wrong.